# Нет доступа из JQ к динамически загруженным элементам

Tags: jquery

Загружаю таблицу из отдельного файла, в таблице есть `input` c `id="in1"`

```
$('#div').load('table.html');
```

Поменять значение не получается

```
$('#in1').value="fdsf";
```

Answer (score -1):

Покурив мануалы - добавил обработчик:

```
$('#data').load('table.html',function() {
    $('#in1').val('gfhgfh');
});
```